Извлечь metadata из запроса в @GrpcService
Написал @GrpcService сервис и тестирую его работу через Postman

запрос принимается. Я не понимаю как прочитать переданные метаданные
@GrpcService
private class SearchServiceGrpc(
    private val searchService: SearchService
) : SearchGrpcKt.SearchCoroutineImplBase() {
  
    override suspend fun calculateV3(request: SearchCalculateRequestProtoV3): SearchResponseProtoV3 {//..}

класс SearchCalculateRequestProtoV3 сгенерирован и описан в .proto файле

Вы имеете ввиду header?

ну как я понимаю в grps нет header есть metadata они должны передаваться на вход запроса и прочитываться

а, перепутал ключ через X-. Есть header при подключении просто. А в вашем случае нужно написать interceptor: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/grpc/grpc_send_receive_metadata.htm
